# Where can I find this game with a sacrifice followed by a long series of checks leading to a discovered mate?

Tags: endgame, tactics, sacrifice, famous-games, identify-this

I am looking for a chess game and frankly, I really know very little about it. I remember seeing it somewhere on the Internet.

The game goes something like this. A player (either White or Black) sacrifices their most important piece, probably the queen. This starts a continuous checking sequence. Check is continuously repeated 10-11 times with the opponent's king always having to play a forced move. The opponent's king is forced to move from their rank to the last one. Then the attacking player moves their king to expose the attack of a rook already there, checkmating the opponent.

I know this is near to no information. I have searched the Internet and this site to find this game. But, as I do not have any concrete information, I am not able to find it.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I believe that the game you speak of is the extremely famous [Lasker-Thomas](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1259009) match in which Lasker forces Black to accept his queen "sacrifice" on move 11. It is followed by a king hunt in which Black's king is forced to the last rank by White, who then finishes the game with the king giving a discovered check from the unmoved a8 rook. The game is notable because White could have chosen the exemplary move 18. 0-0-0#, which is exemplary because castling while also delivering checkmate has been a rare achievement in chess history, but Lasker instead chose the more mundane, in my opinion at the least, 18. Kd2#.

The checking sequence isn't quite 10-11 moves long, but otherwise it fits the bill perfectly, especially with the particular mating move that you described.

```
[Title "Edward Lasker-George Alan Thomas, London England, 10/29/1912"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "20"]

1. d4 e6 2. Nf3 f5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. Bxf6 Bxf6 6. e4 fxe4 7. Nxe4 b6 8. Ne5 O-O 9. Bd3 Bb7 10. Qh5 Qe7 11. Qxh7+ Kxh7 12. Nxf6+ Kh6 13. Neg4+ Kg5 14. h4+ Kf4 15. g3+ Kf3 16. Be2+ Kg2 17. Rh2+ Kg1 18. Kd2#
```

Comment: @bof This was [Lasker's explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/5n66lc/this_is_the_craziest_checkmate_ive_ever_seen/dc9fxg8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x): "Instead of checkmating with Kd2 I could have done it by castling, which would perhaps have been more spectacular, as no player has ever been mated that way before, as far as I know. I actually considered castling, but the efficiency-minded engineer got the better of it and I played Kd2 which required moving only one piece."